# Symfony 3 Looking for Class in Wrong Place

Tags: php, symfony, routes, bundle

I wrote some code in a Symfony 3 project that was working last night, but now when I execute `sf server:run`, it throws the following error:

```
[RuntimeException] 
The autoloader expected class "InventoryBundle\InventoryBundle" to be defined in file"/Users/parth/Sites/debate-inventory/src/InventoryBundle/Tests/InventoryBundle.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.
```

I did some digging, and in the root directory of my bundle I have a file called `InventoryBundle.php`, which contains:

```
<?php

namespace InventoryBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class InventoryBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

However, the system keeps looking for `Tests/InventoryBundle.php`, and I recently discovered there is a file there. The file contains:

```
<?php

namespace InventoryBundle\Tests;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class InventoryBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

I've never used the testing service before so I don't know what's going on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried remove `Tests` folder if you are not going make use of it?

Comment: Update your question with the autoload section of composer.json.  You must have done something to it to impact the search order.